# How to get my live wallpaper icon in Livewallpaper list

Tags: java, android, android-layout, live-wallpaper

How to get my live wallpaper icon in Livewallpaper list.

I am developing a live wallpaper. After running the application
i cannot see icon when selecting livewallpaper.
please see picture below

I can see the Text Flowers HD Wallpaper but not icon.

Thanks for you help in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the android:thumbnail attribute on the wallpaper element in your xml as such:

```
android:thumbnail="@drawable/thumb"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are missing icon attribute in Manifest file

```
 <application 
      android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

or might be in used (hdpi-mdpi-ldpi) drawble resource folder image is not present or changed.